# Configure & Make Fails for openjdk 8 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

i have downloaded the sourcecode of Openjdk 8 using the command

> hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/aarch32-port/jdk8u/ jdk8u

when trying to cross_configure for raspberry pi, i get the following error

```
configure: Found freetype include files at /usr/include/freetype2/ using --with-freetype
configure: Could not find /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so. Ignoring location.
configure: error: Can not find or use freetype at location given by --with-freetype
configure exiting with result code 1
```

whereas the freetype & freetype6-dev is installed on my ubuntu 18.04. please guide

Comment: By the way, you can download a build already made for [Linux on 64-bit ARM from AdoptOpenJDK/Adoptium](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot). Possibly from other vendors too.

Comment: i have to build it myself as i have to modify some files of JDK to customize it as part of my research project.